# Помогите пожалуйста с нюансами git rebase

Tags: git-rebase

Суть вот в чем. У меня есть ветка, основана на старой версии мастера, я хочу ее освежить и сделал rebase master. Однако, вместо того чтобы сравнивать конечную версию мастера и текущую ветку - он сравнивает каждый коммент поверх моего старого мастера, а там их 100+.

Почему я не могу просто 1 раз смерджить и увидеть все конфликты между текущей и последней версией мастера, зачем мне пихает он конфликты на каждом промежуточном коммите? Как сделать чтобы этого небыло?

Я пытался читать мануаллы - но у меня уже едет крыша

Comment: А зачем вы делаете rebase, а не обычный merge ?

Comment: Чтобы сохранить все коммиты? Если я сделаю мердж - я не смогу шарится в промежуточных.... Теперь понятно почему он цепляется к каждому коммиту... потому что я могу заскочить на любой из них а там конфликты?

Тоесть мне тут поможет только мердж?

Comment: кто сказал, что не сможете шариться в промежуточных???

Comment: Ну может я ошибся) Просто подскажите пожалуйста как делают люди обычно в такой ситуации

Comment: Обычно люди не ребейзят ветки на 100+ коммитов.  Но для редких исключений можно посмотреть на [git rerere](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-Rerere) но это не самый простой инструмент. И может действительно проще замержить master в вашу ветку и не заморачиваться

Comment: @Artem обычно люди мержат master в ветку. Это называется "актуализировать до мастера". И да - при merge все коммиты сохраняются. И в ветке и из мастера.